# Use pictures of my MobileMe account in a third party application

Tags: iphone

I have a MobileMe account and I am creating a Iphone application. I would like to let the user of my application see some of the pictures I have on MobileMe.
Is it possible? How?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. I am doing this with an app I have in the app store. If you simply set the URL of your UIWebView in your application to your gallery.me.com/iphone/USERNAME it will pull in a nicely formatted gallery into your app. I am noticing some issues with this on iOS4 but i'll bet this will get fixed soon.